# Convert HEVC files with ubuntu

Tags: convert

I got hevc files working in Ubuntu using instructions [here](http://vladimir-ivanov.net/vlc-does-not-support-the-audio-or-video-format-hevc-unfortunately-there-is-no-way-for-you-to-fix-this/) but playback is not possible on the TV (watching movies on the tv by saving them to flash drive and connecting it) 
So, if possible, I need to convert the hevc to something that the TV can understand

**Edit:** Ok so not only did the kind attempts at helping me not work, but now VLC player is broken and won't play any video file whatsoever. Same goes for mplayer. They still play mp3s.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Transmageddon from Ubuntus bigg bunch of software.
If I can play a video on my mashine, but the TV complains, I use this wery easy point and click codec converter, it seems to use every codec it finds installed and do a great job.
So get it from the software center, and start transcoding the offending mediafiles!

Comment: No matter what I try to convert it to I get this:
Python (v3.4) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: video/x-unknown decoder